# How can I find the module(s) provided by a given Python distribution?

Tags: python, pip

I need to construct a list of modules that are provided by a list of Python distributions specified in a requirements.txt file. The distributions will first be installed so they should be available for inspection locally.

It looks like I should be able to use `pip.req.parse_requirements` to get the list of distributions from the requirements file. From there, how can I find the name of the module(s) that the distributions provide?

Comment: Are you adverse to running a python script with each distribution?

Comment: @GWW I'm not quite sure what you mean but I'm not adverse to any option, really.

Comment: I don't understand your question if you have the requirements.txt then those are the modules, what exactly are you looking for? in fact if they will be installed and inspected then you'll use the contents of requirements.txt to do that.

Comment: "Distributions" are specified in the requirements.txt, not modules. They often have the same names but sometimes do not. See: http://guide.python-distribute.org/glossary.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use the built in [pkgutil](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html#module-pkgutil) module if your python versions are 2.3+

For example,

```
import sys, pkgutil
mods = set()

#You may not need this part if you don't care about the builtin modules
print sys.builtin_module_names
for m in sys.builtin_module_names:
    if m != '__main__':
        mods.add(m)
        #mods.add(m)


for loader, name, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages():
    if name.find('.') == -1:
        mods.add(name)

print mods
```

Answer (score 2):

Since, like you said, distributions are not the modules they contain, we run into a problem: The typical install process for a distribution -- which is, afaik, a collection of packages along with an installer -- is to download, unpack, and then run setup.py, which handles the remainder of the installation process.

The upshot is that, even given a Python distribution, you cannot actually tell what setup.py will do without running it. There may be conventions, and you may be able to pull out a lot of information and formulate a lot of good guesses, but running that 'setup.py' file is really the only way to see what it actually installs into site-packages. Hence, `parse_requirements`, or really any of the pip internals really won't be useful for you, unless you're only interested in distributions.

So, that being said, I think the best way to manage your problem would be to:

1. Set up a virtual environment w/o site packages
2. `pip -r requirements.txt` to actually install all packages
3. Trawl through `sys.path`, looking for .py, .pyc and into subfolders for `__init__.py?` files to build a list of modules.
4. Kill that virtualenv and move on your way.

Step three may be doable in other, better, ways, I'm not sure. Further, you still run the risk of missing dynamically created modules or other trickiness, but this should capture the majority of modules.

**Edit:**

Here's some code that should work for everything but zip files:

```
import sys, os

def walk_modules_os(root):
    def inner_walk(dir_path, mod_path):
        filelist = os.listdir(dir_path)
        pyfiles = set()
        dirs = []
        for name in filelist:
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir_path, name)):
                dirs.append(name)
            else:
                pre, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
                if ext in ('.py', '.pyc', '.pyo'):
                    pyfiles.add(pre)

        if len(mod_path):
            if '__init__' not in pyfiles:
                return
            pyfiles.remove('__init__')
            yield mod_path

        for pyfile in pyfiles:
            yield mod_path + (pyfile,)

        for directory in dirs:
            sub = os.path.join(dir_path, directory)
            for mod in inner_walk(sub, mod_path + (directory,)):
                yield mod

    root = os.path.realpath(root)
    if not os.path.isdir(root):
        return iter([])
    return iter(inner_walk(root, tuple()))

# you could collect as a set of tuples and do set subtraction, too
for path in sys.path:
    for mod in walk_modules_os(path):
        print mod
```

**Edit 2:**

Well, crikey. GWW has the right idea. A much better solution than mine.

Comment: I think this is pretty much the route I'm going to go. 1. Find currently available modules. 2. Install needed packages 3. Find modules available after new packages are installed.